# Какое условие необходимо добавить, чтобы в массиве не выводились отрицательные числа и 0

Tags: javascript

Написал функцию вывода в массив четных чисел, но не понимаю какую условную конструкцию нужно добавить, чтобы в массиве были числа только те, которые больше нуля.

```
function selectEvenNumbers(elem) {
    const arrayNumber = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        if (elem[i] % 2 === 0) {
            arrayNumber.push(elem[i])
        }
    }
    return arrayNumber;
}

console.log(selectEvenNumbers([1, 2, 3, 4, -3, -2, 0, 43434, 3434, -23434, -3434]));
```

Comment: Эм? `elem[i] > 0` очевидно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а в чем сложность?

```
if ((elem[i] % 2 === 0) && (elem[i] > 0))
```

делайте сложные условия через логические операции И, ИЛИ и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо, забыл про логическое И)